# Window function to remove specific records from SQL Server dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have a SQL Server query that returns a dataset showing a person's ID, the entity that person works for, the locations belonging to the entity, the coordinator assigned to the case and the person's status.

```
   ID    EntityName     LocationName      AssignedTo     StatusName
   17       F&S            St. Lucie         A Hardon       Active
   17       F&S            St. Lucie         A Hardon       Withdrawn
   18       F&S            NH                A Hardon       Withdrawn
   20       H&H            NCH               B Reedy        Active
```

I need to eliminate records where the only status for the combination of EntityName, LocationName and AssignedTo is Withdrawn.  So in the dataset above I would want to remove ID = 18 with LocationName = NH.

I've tried using a Window Function, which may be on the right path but I'm not sure how to proceed:

```
   Select id, entityname, locationname, assignedto, statusname
   Into #test
   From Table A

   Select *,
          row_number()over(partition by entityname, locationname, assignedto
                           order by case when statusname = 'Withdrawn' then 1
                                    else 2 end) as rn
  from #test
```

This gives me a result like this:

```
    ID   EntityName   LocationName     AssignedTo     StatusName      RN
    17     F&S          St. Lucie        A Hardon       Withdrawn      1
    17     F&S          St. Lucie        A Hardon       Active         2
    18     F&S           NH              A Hardon       Withdrawn      1
    20     H&H           NCH             B Reedy        Active         1
```

But now I'm stuck on how to continue, or if I'm even going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Can `StatusName` be anything other the two values?

Comment: Yes, there are 7 statuses, but the only one I need to remove is Withdrawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using EXISTS

```
Select *
FROM    #test t1
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM #test t2 
                WHERE t1.EntityName = t2.EntityName 
                      and t1.LocationName = t2.LocationName 
                      and t1.AssignedTo = t2.AssignedTo 
                      and t2.StatusName <> 'Withdrawn')
```

Comment: I think this did it!  But I'm confused as to why it would work.  Why won't this eliminate all 'Withdrawn"  statuses?

Comment: Exists is looking to see if the combination of EntityName, LocationName, AssignedTo exists in the table with a status other than Withdrawn.. So for first record, it takes F&S, St. Lucie and A Hardon searches this combination for any status other than Withdrawn..  Just so happens that it finds the first record (itself) which is Active so it keeps it.  For the second record, it also finds the first record since those fields match and keeps the second row too..    Its like using an  IN () filter, but allows you to look for multiple fields instead of just one

Comment: It took me a while but I think I understand.  It's looking for all records in the first table that match on the 3 fields but do not have a status ='Withdrawn' in the 2nd table.  That will bring back all records from the first table, including 'Withdrawn', since you're not actually filtering from the first table.  If the only record in table 2 is 'Withdrawn' it will be filtered out from table 2, and therefore cannot be joined to table 1.

Answer (score 2):

Think about this a slightly different way.  Count the number that are *not* withdrawn.  If this is 0, then all are withdrawn.

The appropriate window function is a conditional aggregation, rather than a ranking function:

```
select t.*
from (Select t.*,
              sum(case when statusname <> 'Withdrawn' then 1 else 0 end) over
                  (partition by entityname, locationname, assignedto) as num_notwithdrawn
      from #test t
     ) t
where num_notwithdrawn = 0;
```

Comment: When I tried this it eliminated almost all the records(about 1,000) and only kept 2, both with a status = 'Withdrawn."

Comment: @jackstraw22 . . . Is `statusname` ever `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select id, entityname, locationname, assignedto, statusname,
    r   row_number()over(partition by entityname, locationname, assignedto
                   order by CASE statusname WHEN 'Withdrawn' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) as rn Into #test From Table A
Select * from #test LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
       SELECT MAX(rn) MRNO,ID FROM #test GROUP BY ID
  ) T ON T.ID = #TEST.ID WHERE rn = MRNO AND statusname ='Withdrawn'
```

This will eliinate rows with status withdrawn alone for combination of entityname, locationname, assignedto

Comment: Wouldn't this eliminate all the statuses that are not = 'Withdrawn"?

Comment: Edited the query

Answer (score 0):

Delete with an INNER JOIN

```
DELETE T
FROM Table T
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT EntityName,LocationName,AssignedTo
    FROM Table
    WHERE StatusName='Withdrawn'
    GROUP BY EntityName,LocationName,AssignedTo
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)D ON D.EntityName=T.EntityName AND D.LocationName=T.LocationName AND D.AssignedTo=T.AssignedTo
```

Comment: I tried the left join--it was close but didn't quite work.  There are a couple of instances where a person's ID can belong to multiple entities with multiple locations.  If one of those entities only has one record, and that record ='Withdrawn", then all the other records for that person were also being eliminated.  ID=112, Entity = F&S, Location = NE Florida, Status=Withdrawn.  That record is eliminated, as it should be, but all other records for ID = 112 are also being eliminated.

Comment: Yea, then you can't use the ID. I thought it was a identity column, however, it repeats. You would have to remove the MAX(ID) and then join the three group by fields on the outer query to get this to work, however, that could have a performance impact on large datasets if those three fields are not indexed.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds silly, but what is the "T" that is being deleted in "Delete T"?

Comment: T aliases whatever table contains your data. I see, it is confusing. I was using MyTable and Table.Doh! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
WITH CTE 
AS (
Select id, entityname, locationname, assignedto, statusname,
        row_number()over(partition by entityname, locationname, assignedto
                       order by statusname) as rn
  From Table A)
DELETE  from CTE where rn=1  and statusname = 'Withdrawn'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not identify potential deletions using an inner join and then add a simple WHERE clause to delete 'Withdrawn' entries?

```
delete from #table a
inner join (
            select entityname, locationname, assignedto, count(*)
            from #table
            group by entityname, locationname, assignedto
            having count(*) = 1 ) b
            on b.entityname = a.entityname
            and b.locationname = a.locationname
            and b.assignedto = a.assignedto
where a.statusnname = 'Withdrawn'
```

The inner join keeps 'potential' deletions (any combination of e, l and a with just one record), and the subsequent WHERE clause removes the appropriate record(s).